# No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2002

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, nativequery

I'm getting org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2002 when I try to execute this query in a jpa repository;

```
@Query(value = "select t from transactions t inner join accounts a on t.account_id_account_id = a.account_id \n" +
            " where a.account_id = :accountId", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Transaction> getAccountTransactions(@Param("accountId") Integer accountId);
```

Does anyone have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: JDBC type 2002 is STRUCT (java.sql.Types#STRUCT), I believe there is mistake in your native query: `select t from transactions t` - shouldn't it be `select t.* from transactions t`?